# Mahapps Metro Badge in TabItem being clipped

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

If I try to place a badge around the content of a `MetroTabItem`'s header the badge gets clipped by the bounds of the header.

[image: Clipped Header Badge]

I've tried using Snoop to see if the template has any obvious properties causing this but to no avail

Here's the code for the `MetroTabItem`

```
<metro:MetroTabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <metro:Badged BadgePlacementMode="TopRight" BadgeBackground="Transparent">
            <metro:Badged.Badge>
                <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="AlertCircleOutline" Foreground="{DynamicResource ValidationBrush5}"/>
            </metro:Badged.Badge>
            <TextBlock Text="Scripts"
                       Padding="0"
                       Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}"
                       FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(TextElement.FontSize)}"
                       />
        </metro:Badged>
    </TabItem.Header>
</metro:MetroTabItem>
```

I can, however, get the badge from a different control to overlap the header so long as the `Background` of the `TabItem` is set to `Transparent`.

[image: Badge Overlapping Header]

I've checked if there are any other controls above the `TabItem` that don't have a transparent border but even with anything that could overlap this area set to transparent the problem remains

Here's an image with some translucent backgrounds to show bounds.

[image: Clipping Issue with translucent backgrounds]

EDIT:

Here's the visual tree (gathered from Snoop) from the `MetroTabItem` to the header contents. PART_BadgeContainer is the border for the Badge itself, the Border above is the 'Scripts' Container.

[image: Snoop Visual Tree]

EDIT 2:

mm8 asked for a complete example so I've created a default WPF template (vs 2017), added a reference the the current Mahapp.Metro and MahApp.Metro.IconPacks NuGet packages and set up MainWindow.xaml as such:

```
<metro:MetroWindow x:Class="TabItemBadgeLayout.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"    
    xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
        <metro:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
            <metro:MetroTabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <metro:Badged BadgePlacementMode="TopRight" BadgeBackground="Transparent">
                        <metro:Badged.Badge>
                            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="AlertCircleOutline" Foreground="{DynamicResource ValidationBrush5}"/>
                        </metro:Badged.Badge>
                        <TextBlock Text="Scripts"
                           Padding="0"
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type metro:ContentControlEx}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}"
                           FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type metro:ContentControlEx}}, Path=(TextElement.FontSize)}"
                           />
                    </metro:Badged>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </metro:MetroTabItem>
            <metro:MetroTabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <metro:Badged BadgePlacementMode="TopRight" BadgeBackground="Transparent">
                        <metro:Badged.Badge>
                            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="AlertCircleOutline" Foreground="{DynamicResource ValidationBrush5}"/>
                        </metro:Badged.Badge>
                        <TextBlock Text="Tasks"
                           Padding="0"
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type metro:ContentControlEx}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}"
                           FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type metro:ContentControlEx}}, Path=(TextElement.FontSize)}"
                           />
                    </metro:Badged>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </metro:MetroTabItem>
        </metro:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
    </Grid>
</metro:MetroWindow>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="TabItemBadgeLayout.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabItemBadgeLayout"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here's the result:

[image: Minimal Setup]

Comment: For clarity, in the second image the green badge is not overlapping the tab item header. It's _underneath_ it. 'c' in 'Scripts' is over the green icon. It's easy to see it in image 3. Probably irrelevant anyway. You said you have snoop, what is the badge attaching to in the visual tree when you look at it in the snoop ui?

Comment: Ah so it is, sorry, didn't notice. I've edited in a screenshot of the visual tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a margin for the `Badged` elements:

```
<metro:MetroTabControl>
    <metro:MetroTabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="metro:Badged" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type metro:Badged}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 2 0" />
        </Style>
    </metro:MetroTabControl.Resources>
    <metro:MetroTabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <metro:Badged BadgePlacementMode="TopRight" BadgeBackground="Transparent">
                <metro:Badged.Badge>
                    <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="AlertCircleOutline" Foreground="{DynamicResource ValidationBrush5}"/>
                </metro:Badged.Badge>
                <TextBlock Text="Scripts"
                           Padding="0"
                           Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type metro:ContentControlEx}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}"
                           FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type metro:ContentControlEx}}, Path=(TextElement.FontSize)}"
                           />
            </metro:Badged>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </metro:MetroTabItem>
    ...
```

Comment: Putting the margin on the TabItem doesn't work. However, placing a margin on the `metro:Badged` control does avoid the clipping (by making the container bigger) but changes the layout. I guess this is a workaround but ideally I'd like to disable the clipping.

Comment: It certainly works for me. Place the margin on the parent TabControl then.

Comment: It seems to work in the designer but not while running. A margin on the parent doesn't work either (at least for me). Is yours displaying correctly while running/debugging rather than in the designer?

Comment: You should always create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example when you ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see my latest edit. Adding margins onto the `TabItem` or `TabControl` is still not sorting this issue

Comment: It looks like you have to add the margin to the Badged elements. See my edit. The results should be pretty much the same.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a workaround by setting the margin on the `Badged` elements to `0 6 3 0` and then `0 -6 -3 0` on each `TabItem` just to keep them in the same position. Can't work out a way to disable the clipping.

Comment: What would be the difference?

Comment: I have some `TabItem`s that don't need the Badge. If I left the `TabItem`s without the negative margin they would be misaligned with these tabs. The values are just the minimums I found to remove the clipping

Comment: Oh, I think you meant between using margins and disabling the clipping. It's mainly preference, I don't particularly want random margins floating around so if there was a simple way to disable the clipping I'd prefer that

Comment: Works for me. You should add Badged for all Tab Items of the tab control even if you don't want a Badge on it. Specify a -10 Margin on MetroTabControl to re-position the tab control to the original position.